# Bootstrap как уменьшить расстояние

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card col-mb-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="'; echo $img_deck; echo '" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <center>
          <div class="badge badge-glow badge-primary">'; echo $name_deck; echo '</div>

      </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: к сожалению приведенный код показывает только одну карточку, а тут интересна их совместная разметка (полная). я бы так сделал: общий div, а внутри него карточки: <div class="card float-left ml-3 mb-3">...</div>

Comment: это выборка из бд. так что у обеих одинаково все

Comment: интересно расположение их относительно друг друга. очень похоже на то, что у них flex контейнер.

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть http://cards.devmy.online/

Comment: если вас конечно же не затруднит!

Comment: там сбоку справа от каждого блока лишняя область. понять не могу, как убрать. я больше по бэкенду. а тут верстка и встал вопрос.

Comment: у вас grid layout из 3х колонок, внутри колонки идет <div class="col-md-8">, я убрал col-md-8 и карточка растянулась на 1/3

Comment: точно. почему то не пробовал убирать  class="col-md-8". теперь буду думать, как их уменьшить как было

Comment: потому что с уменьшением размера карточки, увеличивается отступ.